# XGBoost parameters that will overweight errors for a specific decile

Tags: python, xgboost

My goal is to make predictions about the bottom decile of my dataset. If I can predict the bottom decile values well (ie. minimize the errors there) then I am not worried about making accurate predictions of the rest of the dataset.

I have tried a classification model, but the problem is that I can't punish big errors (where it predicts bottom decile, but actual value is top decile). This type of error would be very costly for me. Therefore I am assuming I must do a regression instead of a  classifcation?

When I switch to a regression, is there a way of changing parameters such as objective function or evaluation metric to overweight the importance of the predictions in the bottom decile?